# Civic smells of burnt plastic and smokes a little twice a day

Tags: honda, civic, smell, smoke, intermittent-problems

I have a 99 Honda Civic, automatic transmission.

About two weeks ago, for about 10 seconds it started to smell like burnt plastic and a little smoke started going from under the hood. It stopped and happens once or twice a day since then. When this happens, the temperature is OK according the gauge.

I also noticed 2 things:

- a few drops of oil I think that the car didn’t have before.
- the heater is working good, but it seems that some piece of the fan
  is broken (or melted) because when I push the button to change the
  air direction of the fan, it changes but return always to the “head”
  direction.

Comment: Any noise related to the smoke? Have a professional inspect under the hood, no way we can diagnose this issue.

Comment: No noises. except for the smoke and smell, everything has been ok.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a leak from the head cylinder packing it would drop on to the exhaust manifold. I think there are 2 issues at hand here. As for the fan, it could either be a motor going bad or the fan assembly needs replacement.

Go to Honda for a diagnosis of this situation. They'll charge a small fee for this. Share the results with us.